# Redirect URL javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url-rewriting

have something like this: click in page A and redirect to page B, click in page page B redirect to page C, is there any way to get the URL of page A when I am in C page? and check if page A = 'domain.com/aboutus'.

I am not so good in javascript, I try to do this in PHP but is not work very well because the LastURL here is not the page that I want, maybe someone can show me an script example.

```
if (strpos(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl(), 'checkout/cart') !== false) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCart('1');
} else {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCart('0');
}
if (strpos(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl(), 'onestepcheckout/index') !== false) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCheckout('1');
} else {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCheckout('0');
}
```

Thank you

Comment: do you mean to check url of page A when you are in page B?

Comment: I want to check url of page A when I am in page C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use window location or href in javscript

```
  window.location="your URL";
```

or

```
  location.href=URL;
```

Ex.

```
  <script>
  window.location="http://www.tutorialspoint.com";
  </script>
```

Comment: thank you Tosif, you have an example? how this can work? and how can check if page A = 'domain.com/aboutus'

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `document.referrer` but since you want to check url of page A when you are in page C, the best option will be to use a `localStorage`

Comment: ok I understand this, but how will look the code with document.referrer?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the page Url in querystring to C, like http://www.example.com/link/to/page/c?from=link/to/page/a, and then parse querystring to get the from address.

Comment: if you are redirecting from page a to b by using window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/link/to/page/b", then instead do it like window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/link/to/page/b?from=link/to/page/a". And then in page b, [parse the querystring][1] and forward the from to page c, using the same way of a to b redirection.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can store A page url in cookie like this
     document.cookie = window.location.href; 
and At page C you can get value form cookies

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

In page A

```
<script>
localStorage.setItem('pageA_url', window.location.href);
</script>
```

In page C

```
<script>
var pageA_url = localStorage.getItem('pageA_url');
</script>
```

Comment: and this must add on windows load? or is not important? I'm not so good in javascript

Comment: You can set it any where.

Comment: and the pageA_url must be static, or we can get this? how we can setup this if i don;t know the url? we can get the current url?

Comment: Yes the variable name should be fixed otherwise how can you get the value from local storage variable.

Comment: hmm can you take a look at my PHP code? do you think that we can make this code in jquery to function like is in PHP?